# Error updating mongoDB document using Postman

Tags: mongodb, postman

I am trying to update a record from mongoDB collection using Postman.

This is the code I am using to do it.

```
// Update message with id (using a PUT at http://localhost:8080/messages/:message_id)
router.route('/messages/:message_id')
    .put(function(req, res) {
        Message.findById(req.params.message_id, function(err, message) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            // Update the message text
     message.text = req.body.text;
            message.save(function(err) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);
                res.json({ message: 'Message successfully updated!' });
            });

        });
    });
//Updating A Message end.
```

Next, this is the URI I am typing in Postman to update (based on the id key):
localhost:8080/messages/ObjectId("58ab37f9d23f991791490963")

Then I get this error message:
[image]

I am trying to commit to a Bitbucket repository.
What should I change in the URI to make the update valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to drop the `ObjectId` part from what you are posting and just send the id itself then create an ObjectId on the server

`localhost:8080/messages/58ab37f9d23f991791490963`

```
router.route('/messages/:message_id')
    .put(function(req, res) {
        var id = new ObjectId(req.params.message_id)
        Message.findById(id, function(err, message) {
          ...
     })
```